# instantiation of objects as an attribute vs instantiation of objects in most methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, instantiation

Using C# webforms and the included code samples, what would be the correct way, or cons/pros to instantiate objects for the program, as attributes of the class (option 1)? Or in every method the object/s is/are going to be used (option 2)?.
Take into consideration that there are a lot more methods and objects, and while most methods will use the objects, there are a few methods that won't.

**Updates:**

- Variable names are set like that only for example purposes.
- The question is more about any upsides/downsides regarding performance/maintenance/readability/duplication of code?

Option 1:

```
public partial class MyPage : MyBasePage
{
    //Declared as an attribute and instantiated at init
    private MyClass MC;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MC = new MyClass();
        DoSomeStuff();
        DoMoreStuff();
        DoSomethingElse();
    }

    private void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff with MC
    }

    private void DoMoreStuff()
    {
        //Do more stuff MC
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        //Do some stuff WITHOUT MC
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public partial class MyPage : MyBasePage
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        DoSomeStuff();
        DoMoreStuff();
        DoSomethingElse();
    }

    private void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        //Declared and instantiated on every method that needs it
        MyClass MC = new MyClass();
        // Do stuff with MC
    }

    private void DoMoreStuff()
    {
        //Declared and instantiated on every method that needs it
        MyClass MC = new MyClass();
        //Do some stuff with MC
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        //Do some stuff WITHOUT MC
    }
}
```

**Update:**
What about this 3rd option provided by [Sham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5064530/sham)

```
private MyClass _MC;
private MyClass MC
{
    get
    {
        if(_MC == null)
        {
            _MC = new MyClass();
        }
        return _MC;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider lazy loading for this kind of scenario to avoid duplicate code and unnecessary instantiation.

I assume that you are having proper naming convention in your production code.

```
    private MyClass _MC;
    private MyClass MC
    {
        get
        {
            if(_MC == null)
            {
                _MC = new MyClass();
            }
            return _MC;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much whether 1 is simply better than the other. It's more about what exactly you're trying to do. So, declaring it in a method and using it in that method means it will only be available in that scope. If you declare at the class level and then use it within the various methods in that class then you have to be much more careful when you use it. Let me give an example.

On Option 2 you do:

```
private void DoMoreStuff()
{
    //Declared and instantiated on every method that needs it
    MyClass MC MC = new MyClass();
    //Do some stuff with MC
}
```

This means MC is only available INSIDE DoMoreStuff. If you create another MyClass MC MC (not great naming btw) inside another method as well that will be a completely different instance of MC and nothing to do with the first one.

If however you go with Option 1, each method can access it, but that also each one can change it. So if MC has a property called 'Age' which is an int, and one method sets it to 23 and then another method checks that property it should be 23. Another method could come along later and update that property and set it to 64 etc. However, this can be useful for things like services, that offer common methods for doing things.

So, it really depends on MC is meant to do and how it will be used. Does it provide some sort of service to your MyPage that you want various methods to be able access e.g. logging, or is it something that just holds data, like perhaps a person class with things like name, age, height etc.?

Comment: I agree with the "not so great naming", but it was just for example purposes. About what it is trying to be accomplished, it's basically, data read and manipulation. Also, I wasn't referring to something as simple as to the "scope of the variable", but rather as; is there any upsides/downsides regarding performance/maintenance/readability/duplication of code?
One argument that I was told for option number 2 is that it helps with performance as well as with memory, while option number 1 was more heavy and slower since the instantiation is available for the entire class.